# labelling factors and keeping numerical values

Tags: r, package, label, factors

I am having some issues with creating factors that I can refer to by both, the numeric value and the "label".

Supposedly the lfactors package does this, however I have been unable to execute it as such. So, this is what I did:

```
library(lfactors)
cars <- mtcars


str(cars)

'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
```

If we look at the "carb" column (probably reflecting carbon emissions), its a numerical

so using the lfactors package I transformed it:

```
cars$carb <- lfactor(c(1:4),
                     levels = c(1:4), 
                     labels = c("low", "medium", "high", "extreme" ))
str(cars)

'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ carb: Factor w/ 4 levels "low","medium",..: 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ..
```

I noticed that it changed to a factor, as per the package description, so I did my checks

```
levels(cars$carb) 
[1] "low"     "medium"  "high"    "extreme" # correct

cars$carb == "medium"
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[23] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE # correct

cars$carb == 2  
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[23] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE # incorrect
```

I still cant refer to the factor by levels and values, so I wondered if anyone has used this package before or has any suggestions for an alternative?

## An close alternative, but not quite there

Even though it is not perfect, as I can not refer to the factors by value and label, I found an approach that at least allowed me to store both, which I thought might be useful for others in my position:

```
library(sjlabelled)
library(magrittr)
library(sjmisc)

cars <- mtcars
str(cars)

'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...

frq(cars$carb)

x <numeric>
# total N=32  valid N=32  mean=2.81  sd=1.62
 val frq raw.prc valid.prc cum.prc
   1   7   21.88     21.88   21.88
   2  10   31.25     31.25   53.12
   3   3    9.38      9.38   62.50
   4  10   31.25     31.25   93.75
   6   1    3.12      3.12   96.88
   8   1    3.12      3.12  100.00
  NA   0    0.00        NA      NA
```

So this is what we get in its numeric form, the transformation to a factor retains the expected form:

```
cars$carb <- as_factor(cars$carb)

str(cars$carb)

Factor w/ 6 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...

frq(cars$carb)

<categorical>
# total N=32  valid N=32  mean=2.81  sd=1.62

 val frq raw.prc valid.prc cum.prc
   1   7   21.88     21.88   21.88
   2  10   31.25     31.25   53.12
   3   3    9.38      9.38   62.50
   4  10   31.25     31.25   93.75
   6   1    3.12      3.12   96.88
   8   1    3.12      3.12  100.00
  NA   0    0.00        NA      NA
```

Now we have it in categorical form, we can label the values (in this example i'll ignore 6 & 8)

```
cars$carb<- set_labels(
  cars$carb,
  labels = c(
    `1` = "low",
    `2` = "medium", 
    `3` = "high",
    `4` = "extreme"
    ))

frq(cars$carb)

<categorical>
# total N=32  valid N=32  mean=2.81  sd=1.62

 val   label frq raw.prc valid.prc cum.prc
   1     low   7   21.88     21.88   21.88
   2  medium  10   31.25     31.25   53.12
   3    high   3    9.38      9.38   62.50
   4 extreme  10   31.25     31.25   93.75
   6       6   1    3.12      3.12   96.88
   8       8   1    3.12      3.12  100.00
  NA    <NA>   0    0.00        NA      NA
```

Now we can see both, the label and the value, however, there is still an issue calling the data based on the labels

```
cars[cars$carb==1,]
                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Valiant        18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Toyota Corona  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1

cars[cars$carb=="low",]

 [1] mpg  cyl  disp hp   drat wt   qsec vs   am   gear carb
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Any advice regarding factor labelling and a way to call on factors via both the labels and values would really be appreciated. And in the meantime, I hope my alternative helps.

Comment: I'm looking at this line: `cars$carb <- lfactor(c(1:4), ...`. Surely you want to put the `carb` vector as the first argument, not 1:4.

Comment: @Edward that is the correct solution - convert comment to answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a little boo boo at the very beginning.

`cars$carb <- lfactor(c(1:4), ...)`

Should be

`cars$carb <- lfactor(cars$carb, ...)`

**Check**:

```
> mtcars$carb=="medium"
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[25]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE    NA    NA  TRUE

> mtcars$carb==2
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[25]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE    NA    NA  TRUE

> all((mtcars$carb=="medium")==(mtcars$carb==2), na.rm=TRUE)
[1] TRUE
```

I was a little surprised that `cars$carb <- lfactor(c(1:4), ...)` didn't trigger an error, or at least a warning. So I experimented:

```
mtcars$carb <- lfactor(c(1:5),
                        levels = c(1:4), 
                        labels = c("low", "medium", "high", "extreme" ))
```

---

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, carb, value = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, NA)) :
replacement has 5 rows, data has 32
```

---

Which makes me think that R's recycling rules are being used, although one could argue that R should *at least* give a warning for the incorrect command. Something like: `"Warning: recycling vector to match length of dim(cars)[1]"`

Regardless of the error, and lack of warning, you (the OP) then went on to say:

> "I noticed that it changed to a factor, as per the package
>   description, so I did my checks"

I would have tabulated the new vector because I don't always trust my coding ability, and it's always good practice whenever you make any changes to the data. Something like:

```
> table(cars$carb)

    low  medium    high extreme 
      8       8       8       8
```

would probably have been enough. That would then have sent warning bells ringing since you would have been aware that the original `carb` variable contains 6 levels, not 4, as well as the levels having equal frequency counts. You may have then figured out what was wrong with your previous command.

I'm not familiar with the lfactor package. I don't understand why the `lfactor` function doesn't assign the numeric levels for your original incorrect command. If you run the `llevels` function, it returns NULL, which is why your comparison using a numeric value returns FALSE for every element.

```
llevels(cars$carb)
NULL
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, Edward. I made the silly mistake of thinking that the first argument where i put c(1:4) was specifying the values, the second line the levels and the third the labels. Interestingly when I try to apply this to a larger array (eg. cars[ ,9:11] it transforms everything in to a character vector.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Edward, as with the provided guidance, I was able to play around and get the lfactor function to do as I wished.

## An issue applying lfactor to multiple columns

When applying the function to a array of data (rather than a single named object; i.e., cars[,9:11] instead of cars$carb, it transformed the vectors in to characters rather than vectors

```
cars <- mtcars
str(cars)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...

cars[,9:11] <- lfactor(cars[,9:11],
                       levels = c(1:4),
                       labels = c("low", "medium", "high", "extreme"))
str(cars)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ am  : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ gear: chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ carb: chr  NA NA NA NA ...
```

## A solution to this issue

After playing around with self made functions, apply, and a number of other commands, the solution I came up with was, to use for loops:

```
vars <- c("am", "gear", "carb")
for(i in vars){
cars[,i] <- lfactor(cars[,i],
                       levels = c(1:4),
                       labels = c("low", "medium", "high", "extreme"))
}

str(cars)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ am  : Factor w/ 4 levels "low","medium",..: 1 1 1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..- attr(*, "llevels")= int  1 2 3 4
 $ gear: Factor w/ 4 levels "low","medium",..: 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
  ..- attr(*, "llevels")= int  1 2 3 4
 $ carb: Factor w/ 4 levels "low","medium",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..- attr(*, "llevels")= int  1 2 3 4
```

This also allowed me to call on the objects via the label or the value

```
head(cars$gear==3)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

head(cars$gear=="high")
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

I hope this post helps others that may be in a similar boat to myself

Thanks again Edward!